# left click + hold = add checkbox

Tags: jquery

**html**

```
  <button>a</button>
  <div class="headerer">
     <p>visit <a href="http://reigel-codes.co.cc">reigel-codes.co.cc</a></p>
  </div>
```

**problem**

how can I add checkbox after <button> by pressing and hold left click ?.. then stop adding when left click is release...

I have tried so far,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).after('<input type="checkbox">')
  });
})
```

Comment: Off-topic: It's best not to rely on JavaScript's semicolon insertion stuff; always include the semicolons yourself. Semicolon insertion can result in strange and completely avoidable bugs, and of course, if you minify your scripts, the semis *have* to be there.

Comment: For a real life example to where semi colon insertion will bite you, consider this `return \n { success: true  }` in a function. You will find the function will return `null` because of automatic semi colon insertion.

Comment: @alex: Very good example. (Picking a nit: The function will return `undefined`, not `null`.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder That's what I get for not testing it! Thanks, I think I'll update the comment :P

Comment: Just ran out of time to edit it! Well I hope anyone that reads it will read the rest of the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mousedown` doesn't have an automatic repeat, but you could create one via `setInterval` and then turn it off on `mouseup` via `clearInterval`. E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var addHandle, addTarget;

    addHandle = 0;

    $('button')
        .mousedown(function(){
            if (!addHandle) {
                addTarget = $(this);
                addHandle = setInterval(doTheAdd, 250); // Or whatever interval you want
            }
        })
        .bind('mouseup mouseleave', (function(){
            if (addHandle) {
                clearInterval(addHandle);
                addHandle = 0;
                addTarget = undefined;
            }
        });

    function doTheAdd() {
        if (addTarget) {
            addTarget.after('<input type="checkbox">');
        }
    }
});
```

Be sure to test your target browsers, I wouldn't be *100%* certain some of them don't eat `mousedown` and `mouseup` on buttons.

**Edit** Shout out to jAndy for the point about `mouseleave`, edited the above to use it.

Comment: While this is certainly tidier code, you define 2 variables and 1 function on the parent scope which really makes things slower as every reference to them forces the interpreter to move up a step and scan for them. In JS you should be as local as possible.

Comment: @stagas: And in a million iterations, with the above code, it *might* add as much as a millisecond to the total time. :-) Looking for a variable one step out on the scope chain is not a problem. Whereas, using those variables, I've defended against a couple of failure conditions and helped keep the code clear and maintainable. Well worth the trade.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I'm speaking in generally it is best to avoid variables or functions that move up the scope. In a larger app it makes a lot of a difference. Those milliseconds will eventually add up.

Comment: @stagas: Not in my experience (with some fairly large apps, even on IE, the slowest mainstream browser). Certainly you want to avoid doing silly things, but the above is not silly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var checkInterval;
   $('button').mousedown(function(){
     var me=this;                              // store 'this' button
     checkInterval=setInterval(function() {
       $(me).after('<input type="checkbox">'); // add checkbox after button...
     }, 200);                                  // ...every 200ms on mousedown
   }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {  // bind on mouseup or mouseleave
     clearInterval(checkInterval);             // stop adding checkboxes
   });
});
```

Comment: Close, but the `$(this)` in your interval handler function will be wrong. `this` in the interval callback will be `window`, not the button, using that code.